# Which type of condition is it? What is the mood?

Tags: clauses, conditionals, irrealis-mood

> If any person be found guilty, he shall have the right of appeal.

Is it a type-2 conditional clause?

Is it subjunctive mood, conditional mood, or imperative mood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of this as a variation on the first conditional (if + *present* + then *future*).

The "if" clause contains a verb in the subjunctive (*be*). This is a rare, literary and borderline archaic usage of the subjunctive. (The modern and non-archaic use of subjunctive *be*, other than in a few set phrases like "so be it", is principally in mandatives such as "she asked that he *be* arrested").

The sentence could also be expressed as "Should any person be found guilty, he shall have the right to appeal". This would still be somewhat literary but would lack the somewhat archaic feel of "If he be".

Alternatively, we could (and usually would) simply say "If any person is found guilty, he shall have the right to appeal", with the same meaning. In ordinary language we would be more likely to say "will" rather than "shall". However, in the second and third persons, "shall" often (including here) carries a sense of obligation (close to "must"). "Shall" is part of the conventional wording of legislation in many countries - setting out the required consequence of the condition.

Note: another slightly old-fashioned feature of this sentence is that "he" is used in a generic way to refer back to "any person".

Not all English conditionals fit neatly into the traditional categorisation of first, second etc (which was invented for EFL/ESL purposes, is not taught to native speakers and doesn't always accurately reflect their usage).

Comment: What about "Were he to be found guilty, he would have the right of appeal", which implies future tense and is often categorized as subjunctive mood?

Comment: "Were" is a different type of subjunctive (some prefer to call it irrealis). The "if...were...he would" version would be a second conditional.